# CakePHP: Additional select box data (from associated model) appended to existing select option

Tags: forms, cakephp, model, rdbms

So far, I don't think this is possible as I've been on it for 3.5 hours now. No luck.

I have a form.

I have a select field (with select options of course) which I want to display associated data next to the select items.

For example:

On my **Add Plan** form, I have a select box titled Plan Details. Plan Detail (model) has a Plan Detail Note (model) (PlanDetailNote belongs to PlanDetail) which is associated. In other words, each Plan Detail has a Note about it in the plan_detail_notes table.

I want to know if it is humanly possible with cakephp to display it like so:

**Select Plan Detail:**
[Plan Detail Option 1] - [Plan Detail Note]
[Plan Detail Option 2] - [Plan Detail Note]
[Plan Detail Option 3] - [Plan Detail Note]
[Plan Detail Option 4] - [Plan Detail Note]

As you can see the, the note is appended to the normal select option BUT is just static for viewing only - does not need to be saved.

Is this possible with CakePHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just another thought, if what you actually want is

```
<select>
  <option value="1">[Plan Detail Option 1] - [Plan Detail Note]</option>  
  <option value="2">[Plan Detail Option 2] - [Plan Detail Note]</option>
  ...
  <option value="N">[Plan Detail Option N] - [Plan Detail Note]</option>
</select>
```

Then you could manually create the list using the getAll query (assuming the relationships are properly created)

[ in the controller ]

```
$plans_list = array();
$plans = $this->Plan->findAll();
foreach($plans as $row) {
    $plans_list["{$row['Plan']['id']}"] = "{$row['Plan']['name']} - {$row['PlanDetail']['note']}";
  }
$this->set('plans_list', $plans_list);
```

[ and then in the view ]

```
<?php echo $form->select('Plan.id', $plans_list); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks very much : ) This set me on the right track. I added my code below and a sample screenshot of the output. The findAll() does not seem to be valid in 1.3, so I went with find('all'). and I had to modify the $this-> depth to included the deeper related model PlanDetail. I know it was impossible for you to know my relations w/ out seeing my table schema. Thanks for the great direction : )

Answer (score 0):

Haven't worked with Cake for a while, but in your Plan Details controller could you not append the Plan Detail Note before you send it off to the view?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like what you want to do is display the plan detail note as text in a div next to the select box. When you select an option, you want the text in the div to be updated to the plan detail note of the selected option.

If that is what you want to happen, then that will require some ajax work. basically you will observe the field of your select box for an 'onChange' event. That event will update the innerHtml of the div with your plan detail note.

I like to store the plan detail notes as a javascript array or object, then onChange, set the div innerHtml to the value in the javascript array.

Comment: I appreciate your idea : ) I am just not too versed with using the Ajax helpers and doing all that. I think there is a way to append to fields data together in the controller with the find(list.. option that sets up the relation. Looking for the simplest way at this point : )

Answer (score 0):

zeroSkills,

Based on your concept I was able to get it working with some adjustments. Here is what I did:

In the add.ctp (view)

...

```
echo $this->Form->select('plan_detail_id',$plans_list);
```

...

In function add() (in the plans_controller.php)

...

```
$plans_list = array();
$plans = $this->Plan->PlanDetail->find('all');
foreach ($plans as $row) {
    $plans_list["{$row['PlanDetail']['id']}"] = "{$row['PlanDetail']['name']} - {$row['PlanDetailNote']['name']}";
}
$this->set('plans_list', $plans_list);
}
```

...

I did not even need to mess with my Model which was a relief!

Here is a link to an example of the option output:

http://prntscr.com/1jmid

As you can see, I appended the "Under 65" or "Over 65" based on the value of an associated table PlanDetailNote.

Comment: And as a cherry on top, it's always good to do a sort of your selections to make it easier for data entry like: $plans = $this->Plan->PlanDetail->find('all', array('order' => array('PlanDetail.name ASC')));